# Problema ao inserir dados em um vetor

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

Tenho as classes Porta, Edificio e o main:

```
public class Porta {
boolean aberta;
String cor;
double dimensaoX, dimensaoY, dimensaoZ;

void abre() {
    this.aberta = true;
}
void fecha() {
    this.aberta = false;
}
void pinta(String cor) {
    this.cor = cor;
}
boolean estaAberta() {
    boolean estaAberta = false;
    if(aberta == true) estaAberta = true;
    return estaAberta;
}



public class Edificio {
String cor;
int totalDePortas;
int totalDeAndares;
Porta portas[];
int elementos = 0;

void pinta(String cor) {
    this.cor = cor;
}

int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
    int qtdPortasAbertas=0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
        if(portas[i].aberta == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
    }
    return qtdPortasAbertas;
}

void adicionaPorta(Porta porta) {
    for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
        if(this.portas[i] == null) this.portas[i] = porta;
    }
}

int totalDePortas() {
    int totalPortas=0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
        if(this.portas[i] != null) totalPortas++;
    }
    return totalPortas++;
}

void adicionaAndar() {
    this.totalDeAndares = totalDeAndares+=1;
}

int totalDeAndares() {
    return this.totalDeAndares;
}


public class Exer05 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //A
    Porta p1 = new Porta();
    p1.abre();
    p1.fecha();
    p1.pinta("Azul");
    p1.pinta("Verde");
    p1.dimensaoX = 1.80;
    p1.dimensaoY = 1.00;
    p1.dimensaoZ = 1.80;
    if(p1.estaAberta() == true) System.out.println("A porta"
            + " está aberta");
    else System.out.println("A porta está fechada");

    //B
    Edificio ed = new Edificio();

    Porta p2 = new Porta();
    p1.fecha();
    ed.adicionaPorta(p2);
    Porta p3 = new Porta();
    p1.abre();
    ed.adicionaPorta(p3);
    Porta p4 = new Porta();
    p1.abre();
    ed.adicionaPorta(p4);
    Porta p5 = new Porta();
    p1.abre();
    ed.adicionaPorta(p5);
    Porta p6 = new Porta();
    p1.abre();
    ed.adicionaPorta(p6);
    Porta p7 = new Porta();
    p1.fecha();
    ed.adicionaPorta(p7);

    ed.quantasPortasEstaoAbertas();

}
```

Acontece que quando chamo o método adicionaPorta() na classe main, acontece o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.edu.utfpr.exer05.Edificio.adicionaPorta(Edificio.java:23)
at br.edu.utfpr.exer05.Exer05.main(Exer05.java:24)
```

Como resolver?

Obrigado

Comment: Olá, eu também sou novato em programação mas tens de, no método onde puseste quantas portas tens de por +1 no ciclo mesmo a frente de onde está o método de ver o comprimento da string, desculpe se n consigo explicar bem mas prefiro falar inglês :p

Comment: Já resolvi, utilizei a coleção ArrayList para isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara, porque você não tenta usar o ArrayList do java.util?
É mais fácil para inserir e tratar os dados da Array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Edificio{
    private List<Porta> portas = new ArrayList<Porta>();
    public void adicionaPorta(Porta porta){
        this.portas.add(porta);
    }
}
```

Desse jeito você cria um ArrayList do tipo Porta, e com o método `add` você adiciona um novo item para ele.
Depois se precisar, pode buscar o valor usando o método `get`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou ler sobre!

Comment: Pesquisei sobre e implementei, deu certo também, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

@Rodrigo,
Você somente declarou o atributo `Porta porta[]`, por isso está dando `NullPointerException`;

No caso faltou inicialzar:

```
Porta porta[] = new Porta[100]; //um vetor de 100 portas
```

Ref.: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-estrutura-dados/vetores/

Comment: Deu certo dessa forma, obrigado. Vou continuar o exercício e caso não de erro, reporto aqui, valeu!!

Comment: Boa!, 
Não recomendo a utilização dessa estrutura de dados não, mas para fins de aprendizado tá valendo;

Vale estudar o ArrayList tb.

Comment: Mais uma coisa, na classe Edificio, o método quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() não retorna as portas abertas, sabe o por quê?